# Creating a "game" with 2 players and referee (processes) using C in Linux based system

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, fork

i'm now trying to create a game for Linux based systems, in which there are three processes:

1. Referee - Main process
2. Blue Player - First child process
3. Red Player - Second child process

Of course the two child processes are created using the `fork()` function.

Now everything is created, i'm using shared memory to store the board and some more variables that are common to the three processes.

My problem is when i'm trying to think about how am i going to implement the turn based game - i created a common boolean variable that points whether the game is still on or finished, and one that decides who's turn is it.

Now we are entering the shared part, i had paused the two child processes and sent a signal to the first child process to "wake him up", but from now on how do i keep all the three processes together and synchronized (referee wakes first processes, it finishes the turn and paused, than referee wakes the second one, and so on...)

I guess i have to keep that part in some kind of `while(game_finished == FALSE)` loop but from there i'm stuck.

How do i implement that game in the way i just explained? Thanks.

Comment: Dou you need to fork?, threading each player seems easier, so the referee can wake them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several alternatives, but a busy-wait is among the worst.  You could consider a solution built on shared semaphores, but I would choose one based on pipes.  A process will block performing a read on an open file descriptor from which no data is presently available, so that's an easy way to make the various processes wait for one another, so as to take turns.

Just create pipes in each direction between the referee process and each player process.  On each turn, each player process attempts to read one byte from the referee.  It will not proceed until the referee writes something to its end of the pipe.  As a bonus, the byte(s) that is written can convey additional data / instructions, so as, for instance, to distinguish between "make a play" and "game over".  Of course, the same sort of synchronization works in the other direction, too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use separate processes, one way of achieving what you want is using barriers. You already have a "controller" process and the players have a simple state behavior (wait one turn, play one turn). The controller process (the referee, as you call it) can signal the child processes the state of the game, and synchronize everything at barriers.

Below is the pseudocode of a simplistic version:

```
// Controller
while (game_running) {
    barrier 1
    // wait for player1
    barrier 2
    // wait for player2
}

// Player 1
while (game_running) {
    barrier 1 // Sinchronize with controller
    // do stuff
    barrier 2
}

// Player2
while (game_running) {
    barrier 1 // Wait for player1
    barrier 2
    // do stuff  
}
```

A few additional barriers are probably required to allow the controller process the data from players and then synchronize the players, but this is a basic mechanism of controlling multiple players.

For more details about the barrier functionality provided by the linux API, check this link: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html

Comment: I don't think barriers are the right synchronization primitive for this job.  Their usual use to more or less the opposite of making threads take turns -- they are used to gather threads at a synchronization point until enough arrive there, and then to let them *all* proceed together.

Comment: Additionally, I am uncertain about (and find no documentation for) the Pthreads barrier implementation working across multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2-player game code. Which is implemented using pipe. Hope this will work for you.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int fd1[2], fd2[2], fd3[2], fd4[2];
char turn='T';
printf("This is a 2-player game with a referee\n");
pipe(fd1);
pipe(fd2);
if(!fork())
player("TOTO", fd1, fd2);
close(fd1[0]); // parent only write to pipe 1
close(fd2[1]); // parent only reads from pipe 2
pipe(fd3);
pipe(fd4);
if(!fork())
player("TITI", fd3, fd4);
close(fd3[0]); // parent only write to pipe 3
close(fd4[1]); // parent only reads from pipe 4
while(1){
printf("\nReferee: TOTO plays\n\n");
write(fd1[1], &turn, 1);
read(fd2[0], &turn, 1);
printf("\nReferee: TITI plays\n\n");
write(fd3[1], &turn, 1);
read(fd4[0], &turn, 1);
}
}

void player(char *s, int *fd1, int *fd2){
int points=0;
int dice;
long int ss=0;
char turn;
while(1){
read(fd1[0], &turn, 1);
printf("%s: playing my dice\n", s);
dice =(int) time(&ss)%10 + 1;
printf("%s: got %d points\n", s, dice);
points+=dice;
printf("%s: Total so far %d\n\n", s, points);
if(points >= 50){
printf("%s: game over I won\n", s);
kill(0, SIGTERM);
}
sleep(5); // to slow down the execution
write(fd2[1], &turn, 1);
}
}
```